# Assertion error while using std::copy_if for std::vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, assertions

Why am I getting runtime error while trying to do:

```
std::vector<int> vi;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vi),10,rand);  

std::vector<int> vi_1;
vi_1.reserve(vi.size());
std::copy_if(vi.begin(),vi.end(),vi_1.begin(),std::bind2nd(std::greater<int>(),-20000));  
//Here (in copy_if) I'm getting assert error.
```

Comment: what does the error message say?

Comment: Are you sure you need `vi_1.reserve(vi.size());` and not `vi_1.resize(vi.size());`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reserve doesn't actually create the objects, it only guarantees, that every call that's going to grow the vector to the given limit is going to be O(1). Use `resize`.

Comment: You can also use reserve and std::back_inserter(vi_1)

Comment: If think I would rather keep the `reserve` and use a `back_inserter`, to avoid creating useless values.

Comment: `push_back` is guaranteed amortized O(1), even without `reserve(n)`.  `reserve` guarantees no reallocation up until the vector becomes larger than `n`.  This has two important effects: the constant factor in O(1) is really constant (an not just an amortized constant), and very small; and no iterators, references or pointers to already existing elements will be invalidated

Answer (score 1):

`vi_1.reserve` merely reserves memory, but does not change the actual size of the vector. For that you have to use `resize`.